# Merging sub-arrays (and adding the third position) within an array, if and only if the first two positions are the same

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of sub-arrays:

```
[ ["a","b",54],["b","c",89],["b","c",84],["c","b",78],["a","b",83],["a","c",87] ]
```

I want to merge the sub-arrays (and add the 3rd position number (2nd index) together) IF AND ONLY IF the first two positions are exactly the same.

The result I am looking for would be:

`[ ["a","b",137],["b","c",173],["c","b",78],["a","c",87] ]`

(the final order of the sub-arrays inside the array is not important)

How can I do this?

**EDIT: Use of lodash is not required (but, personally I can't get it to work using lodash)**

Comment: Have you tried anything? Grouping and merging elements is a super common operation, so a quick Google search pulls up [many useful results](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+group+elements+by+multiple+keys). Please specify what you've tried in order to distinguish your question.

Comment: @4castle  I was looking for something better than loops. (some kind of library use, such as lodash).

Comment: I have a nice solution for you, but please post an attempt. Even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the power of a hash table and build a new result set by iterating the array.

```js
var array = [["a", "b", 54], ["b", "c", 89], ["b", "c", 84], ["c", "b", 78], ["a", "b", 83], ["a", "c", 87]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.slice(0, 2).join('|');
    if (!hash[key]) {
        result.push(hash[key] = a.slice());
        return;
    }
    hash[key][2] += a[2];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```